# Pandas GroupBy and Sum python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello everyone Im trying to group data by Date and then sum the second column, but I not getting the information as i need

This is my data:

```
|Day       |Messages|Codes  |
|----------|--------|-------|
|2020-08-25|647     |34234  |
|2020-08-25|6,396   |3425645|
|2020-08-25|16,615  |64564  |
|2020-08-26|16,066  |45654  |
|2020-08-26|4,716   |343234 |
|2020-08-26|748     |35455  |
|2020-08-28|571     |343423 |
|2020-08-28|14      |3423   |
|2020-08-28|1       |SDAS2  |
```

The output that i need is like this:

```
|Day       |Messages|Codes  |
|----------|--------|-------|
|2020-08-25|23658   |34234  |
|          |        |3425645|
|          |        |64564  |
|2020-08-26|21530   |45654  |
|          |        |343234 |
|          |        |35455  |
|2020-08-28|586     |343423 |
|          |        |3423   |
|          |        |SDAS2  |
```

First need to group by Day and then sum the Messages column , I tried with the next lines but doesn't work as i expect :c

```
#1
read = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
read.groupby(['Day'])
read.groupby(['Messages']).sum()
read.to_html('test.html',index=False)

#2
read = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
group_day = read.groupby(['Day','Messages']).sum()
group_day.to_html('test.html')
  
#3
read = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
read.groupby('Day')[['Messages','ShortCode']].sum()
read.to_html('test.html',index=False)
```

Comment: `read.assign(Messages=read.groupby("Day")["Messages"].transform("sum"))`?

Comment: why some of the columns are not in expected output? But `Codes` columns has still values in that rows

Answer (score 0):

This might get you close to what you need:

`read.groupby(['Day','Messages','ShortCode']).size().reset_index().set_index(['Day','Messages'])`